# How to change time zone in xml audit file (Oracle 11g)?

Tags: java, xml, oracle, oracle11g, audit-trail

i'm working on a project in java to display everything what happend in my Oracle 11g Database. For this i started using the Audit Trail in XML format because i want to use it in my network.

I created a user for example to try this out. But my Problem is the wrong timestamp in the xml files and i would need it to check the time of connections etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Audit xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/dbserver_audittrail-   11_2.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracleas/schema/dbserver_audittrail-11_2.xsd">
<Version>11.2</Version>
<AuditRecord><Audit_Type>1</Audit_Type><Session_Id>1260546</Session_Id><StatementId>1</StatementId><EntryId>1</EntryId><Extended_Timestamp>2016-10-01T15:59:47.473000Z</Extended_Timestamp><DB_User>CC</DB_User><OS_User>Admin-PC\Admin</OS_User><Userhost>WORKGROUP\ADMIN-PC</Userhost><OS_Process>1780:2512</OS_Process><Terminal>ADMIN-PC</Terminal><Instance_Number>0</Instance_Number><Action>100</Action><TransactionId>0000000000000000</TransactionId><Returncode>0</Returncode><Comment_Text>Authenticated by: DATABASE</Comment_Text><Priv_Used>5</Priv_Used><DBID>1434098587</DBID>
</AuditRecord>
<AuditRecord><Audit_Type>1</Audit_Type><Session_Id>1260546</Session_Id><EntryId>2</EntryId><Extended_Timestamp>2016-10-01T15:59:50.798000Z</Extended_Timestamp><DB_User>CC</DB_User><OS_User>Admin-PC\Admin</OS_User><Userhost>WORKGROUP\ADMIN-PC</Userhost><Terminal>ADMIN-PC</Terminal><Instance_Number>0</Instance_Number><Action>101</Action><Returncode>0</Returncode><DBID>1434098587</DBID>
</AuditRecord>
</Audit>
```

The Timestamp here is set at 15:59 but in my timezone it should be 17:59 (UTC+01:00). Then i tried this statement to check the timezone and curiously it was the right time.

SELECT db_user, extended_timestamp, action FROM v$xml_audit_trail WHERE db_user='CC' ORDER BY extended_timestamp DESC;

```
DB_USER      EXTENDED_TIMESTAMP                      ACTION
CC           01.10.16 17:59:50,798000  +02:00        101
```

Do anyone know how to set the right timezone for the xml format?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should probably be asked on the [DBA StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site as it is not immediately about programming but db setup/config/settings.

Comment: 15:59 (at UTC) + 1 hour is 16:59 - not 17:59!

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#BCGHBHJC):

> `Extended_Timestamp` indicates the time of the audited operation (timestamp of user login for entries created by `AUDIT SESSION`), in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) or Greenwich Mean Time (GMT). This field only appears in the XML audit files, not the OS text audit files.

There doesn't seem to be anyway to change that, unless you transform the XML in the file later.

The timestamp is correct, it's just always in UTC. Whatever is going to consume this XML (you said you want to use it 'in your network') should be able to recognise that, and convert to other time zones if needed, but doing everything in UTC can be simpler anyway.

As an alternative you could generate your own XML from the `v$xml_audit` table with the data in whatever format(and timezone) you want, using the built-in XML generation tools (such as `dbms_xmlgen`).